# Connect from LocalStack lambda function to a database container using docker-compose service name

Tags: docker-compose, localstack

I'm trying to connect from a lambda function in localstack to a database running in another container, but the lambda function can't resolve the service name.

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'my_db'
      MYSQL_USER: 'admin'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - development

localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    hostname: localstack
    container_name: localstack
    environment:
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2
      - EDGE_PORT=4566
      - SERVICES=s3,lambda,apigateway,sqs
      - DEBUG=1
      - HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL=localstack
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_USER=admin
      - DB_PASSWORD=password
    networks:
      - development
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - '4566-4583:4566-4583'
    volumes:
      - "${TEMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"

networks:
  development:

volumes:
  my-db:
```

The problem is that `db` can be resolved from the localstack container (e.g. `docker-compose exec localstack ping db`), but the lambda function says `db` is unresolvable.

I thought that you could add `LAMBDA_DOCKER_NETWORK=development` [as an environment variable](https://github.com/localstack/localstack#lambda-configurations) to the localstack service to connect the lambda functions to that network (see [discussion](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/884)), but when I do that I get an error message saying `network development not found`

```
docker.errors.NotFound: 404 Client Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.41/containers/f98dc74016048bc2295cf1bbf4af09c03e9a78faf5b1462f1130a76e0ca4f850/start: Not Found ("network development not found")
```

I also see this:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.41/containers/1071c60ce1dd44800c38f726ef526388ce1a090bb1e394724cdfcbb76fb7e906/start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the way to connect to the correct network is to set this in the `environment`:

```
LAMBDA_DOCKER_NETWORK=<networkname>
```

So in the above example:

```
LAMBDA_DOCKER_NETWORK=development
```

[documentation](https://github.com/localstack/localstack#lambda-configurations)

Comment: I see you had `s3` service enabled. Does this solution work triggering lambda from an `s3` upload? From my tinkering it seems if you change the lambda network then that means localstack infrastructure that's on the `localstack` network can no longer see it.

Comment: I got this working too, but `LAMBDA_DOCKER_NETWORK` isn't necessary because docker compose automatically bridges services with default networks it creates. If you migrate your `docker run` command into another `service` in your compose file, `localstack` can be resolved by your db and vice-a-versa. The second step is to ensure your db has remote access, and that procedure varies by technology, but for postgres they default to accessibility over localhost and you need to explicitly enable CIDR ranges for other docker networks to access it such as localstack.